# PHP MYSQL unable to store object properties in table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to add iterate through an object and add those object properties to mysql database. Using:

```
//This works
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table ($ID int primary key auto_increment not null)";
mysql_query($sql);
//This works
function iterateObject($obj, $name='') {
  foreach ($obj as $key=>$val) {
    $myName = ($name !='') ? $name . "_" . $key : $key;
    if ( is_object($val) || is_array($val) ) {
      iterateObject($val, $myName);
    } else {
      //This works
      $sql = ("ALTER TABLE home_timeline ADD COLUMN $myName VARCHAR(256);");
      mysql_query($sql);

      //This doesn't work
      $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO home_timeline ($myName) VALUES ($val);");
      mysql_query($sql2);
      print "$myName - $val <br />";
    }
  }
}
```

The table is created and altered so that each iteration adds a new column to the table but when I try and add values to that column (second sql statement) everything is null and the script creates 20+ rows rather than having all the values appear on one row in the relevant column. Could someone help?

Comment: try to see what is the error , like using this code if (mysql_errno()) {
  echo $error = "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$sql2\n<br>";}

Comment: It looks to me like you're going to have a bunch of rows with a bunch of columns, but each row will only have one value in it. Is that what you really want? Also, why do you use a variable for the table name in the `CREATE` statement but use `home_timeline` in your other queries? Are they unrelated?

Comment: I'd phrase it as *my code unable to store...* rather than "PHP MySQL". I can assure you that HP andMysql can store anything, if used properly

Comment: @jswolf19 that's exactly the problem - I want all the values to sit in relevant column but all on the same row? The reason why I used variable and then home_timeline was because the variable doesn't seem to be available in the function - brought up error when I tried to use it before.

Comment: `INSERT` always creates a new row or rows (unless it duplicates a unique key, in which case no changes occur to the table). `UPDATE` is used to modify a row. More importantly, though, are you creating a table that will only have one row in it? That seems very much overkill. If not, then your code here would only work for the first row, anyway, as you would not want to continue to alter the table while inserting the second object. As AlexanderMP suggests, serialization might be better, but at the least I imagine you should rethink your database structure.

Answer (score 2):

why not use functions like `serialize()` and `unserialize()` when converting objects to/from string?

second: if `$val` is string, then in the query put the string delimiters

```
"INSERT INTO home_timeline (`$myName`) VALUES ('$val');"
```

though inserting parameters via concatenation is a very bad practice prone to SQL injection.

If you have further problems, output the query before execution and put it here. You might be experiencing the case when you got a lot of columns which can't be nulls, and have no default values. Also output the table structure here.

Comment: i've included the string delimiters as you suggest and that has put the values into the database - my issue is that the values are showing on different rows, for example: id, text, user shows row 1 id=1, text=null, user=null. row 2 id=2, text=some text, user=null. row 3 id=3, text=null, user=some user. The output of the query is INSERT INTO home_timeline (`text`) VALUES ('this is the text');

Comment: I think the issue is the php loop rather than mysql - it's looping the values in but within different rows

Comment: nope, it's in your SQL. You are inserting 1 value per row, what did you expect? INSERT statement inserts one row, and you only specify one single value.